# How to do a very large number of HTTP requests in shortest time

Tags: c++, http

So we have a very huge database which has around 300,000 urls. These urls have to be pinged and get data from.(these urls are radio stations which are playing song. The data is metadata)

Some of them are sometimes inactive and sometimes active.
On any given time, around 80,000 are active. Some respond slow, some respond quickly. I have a server and I am thinking to do this using c++
My goal is to ping and parse(or crawl) them within 1 minute and keep repeating the process because information(the song playing on them) can change over time. ranging from 2-7 minutes mostly. But I am not sure if it is possible. 
What should be my approach to do it?
I have thought of creating two programs, one to test if the url is active or not and run it twice a day. And how much time it generally takes to respond. Does it usually respond slow or whether it is responding slower now.

And the other to do the actual crawling where fastest will be crawled first and some dedicated threads for urls which respond faster.

Please i would love more better ideas or better solutions for it. Can any one tell me how to do the maths to find out the number of dedicated threads i should allot to each for getting the results in least number of time

Comment: Why is this tagged with `mathematical-optimization` ?

Comment: There are easier languages to do work with HTTP. If you don't know what you are doing, I recommend starting with one of them. get a prototype up and running, and then if, after optimizing the program, it's still too slow, consider migrating to C++.

Comment: The typical rule of thumb for determining determining how many threads you want is asking, "How many cores do I have?"

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I am sorry if you are unable to see it. But this question requires a mathematical solution to find out the most efficient use of resources so that the task can be done in minimum time.

Comment: @user4581301 the machine has 16 cores. I have made a prototype in C++

Comment: Jmeter perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need performance of your CPU (not your bottleneck at the moment), but you need to avoid network layer stall... if the request timeout is 60 seconds, and you have 16 threads, and hit 16 very slow servers (which will time-out eventually), you are generally stalled for 60 seconds and not processing anything more.

So I would start with let's say 500 threads (and like 15-30s timeout, if you know the very slow radios are capable to fit even this), and keep some statistic about their turnaround, and keep adding more working threads dynamically for every original which didn't get response within 2-3 secs. 80000/500 = 160, so each "normally quick" worker thread has then to ping around 160 urls, if each does take 2 seconds, that's still 320 = 5min! So 500 sounds like minimum.

That said, having 500+ threads will somewhat burden CPU and memory (not sure how much, with decent thread/memory model implementation 500 doesn't sounds like much for modern x86 CPU with GB of RAM, even 5000 sounds still reasonable), but I would worry lot more about the network layer and about possible firewalls around, you need server-grade like network for such amount of requests (if I would try something like that from my home, my own router would filter me out with default settings, detecting it as some kind of DoS attack).

So get some statistic how long the request on average take, then take your target time (2-7min), and divide the number of urls by those, like average ping 5s, round time 3min = 300,000/(3*60/5) = 8333.33 threads at least needed. Then you will have to profile your app to verify, that with 8000 threads it will not choke on something else, but it will really handle the task as expected.

(other option is to fire asynchronous http request from single thread, but that sort of creates its own threads for each task any way, so I would rather manage the threads myself, and use synchronous http calls)

And thinking about dynamic grow mechanics... you can keep some counters about how many new requests were added in last second, and how many finished (either responded or failed), and after few seconds of running these should start to form some kind of "throughput" statistic, then if throughput is under desired threshold, you can add more threads.

About active/inactive... keep the response time/last-seen/last-check together with url, and add some further logic to check url only when it makes sense (like not within next 60s, if it did just respond, or check inactive just after 6h from last test). You need also avoid checking the same url in two different threads at the same time, so some central manager code should feed the threads with target (maybe some FIFO thread-safe queue ... actually you can use its size to estimate how well the worker threads are processing it, so you can add more threads when you see the queue is not emptying fast enough = that avoids adding the statistic code to thread themselves).

Comment: First thing, I was not aware of the number of threads possible on our current systems. So thanks for that. Yes I do have a dedicated system. Bought specially for this purpose.
I was thinking of maintaining two queues. One for slow responding, the other for fast responding and allocating a limited number of cores for them.

Comment: Sounds OK to me, but I'm not sure if it's worth the hassle, as even in the fast queue you need to proceed \*many\*requests, so you will need more like hundreds of request per second, than some limited number, so sorting the urls between slow/fast doesn't sound so appealing to me, even if you will consider "fast" with under 3s response, 16 threads will do only about 300-1000 checks per minute = too slow. And the CPU shouldn't be your bottleneck, unless you have very slow code around the task, most of the time CPU should be in idle, waiting for network response (creating 300k requests is fast).

Comment: I am confused, you say 16 threads will only do 300-1000 checks per minute and then you say cpu will not be the bottleneck. There might be urls which are like totally dead so they can delay the response thats why I am creating two queues if that makes sense.

Comment: uhm, if you do synchronous requests, then each thread is doing only single request at one moment, so if request takes 5s to respond, the thread will do only 12 requests per minute. While the CPU will be idling, waiting for response (CPU itself can prepare about billion of bytes in single second, so you can max-out network card output buffer easily even with some Intel Atom mobile CPU, if you focus just on that). If you use asynchronous requests, then single thread is enough, because the further threads will be created by the asynchronous logic = less control over them.

Comment: got it thanks. The network limit is 10Gbit/sec I think it wont be a problem. So it is feasible i guess?

Comment: I think it's a matter of few hours to create fake server, responding with random delays random strings, and connect two computers and run some tests between them to see how the resources are going... sounds definitely feasible, if you will use some reasonable DB and C++, this should hardly max anything. Actually if you will not balance the ping time well, you may end up as abuser on the radio server side, getting IP ban (I think if you would max-out everything, you would be probably capable to ping each station every second). Still plenty of room to do something stupid, so good to reason...